# How to add pager by ajax Call?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form where you select a year from checkbox and then get all users registered for that year. Since the list can get very long I wanted to use a pager. Initially I just wrote an ajax call on checkbox and returned list of users as markup.

However I have difficulty adding pager to this markup that I returned by ajax call.

```
pager_default_initialize(10, 10);

    $form['pager'] = array(
      '#type' => 'pager',
    );
```

I used the above syntax to add pager. However I am not sure how to feed my content into this pager.

```
$form['years'] = array(
      '#title'=>"Select Years",
      "#type"=>"checkboxes",
      "#options"=>$options,
      "#ajax"=>[
        'callback'=>'::userCallback',
        'event'=>'change',
        'wrapper'=>'user_markup',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Generating users...'),
        ],
      ]

    );
$form['user_m'] = array(
"#type"=>"hidden",
"#markup"=>"None",
'#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['user_markup'],
      ],
);

function userCallback(){
//Code to get userlist from database in array $user
$userlist = implode(",",$user);
return ["#markup"=>"div id='user_markup'> $userlist </div>"]
}
```

The other option that I found was using tableselect instead. With tableselect it is easier to add pager.
However when I used tableselect, ajax call doesn't properly fill the options value. I had a weird issue where if there are two values in tableselect and if I update those options to single value with ajax, it still has two rows. One row has the updated value, the other row is empty.

What will be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. How are you attempting to insert the pager? What goes wrong when you try? Please update your question with more information and please share any relevant code and error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I just updated my question

Comment: At first glance, I wonder why you don't pre-populate the list (as a select or tableselect) with all users, then rely on front-end JS to hide ineligible options. Not having to use AJAX will bring down the learning curve considerably. Also, have you checked out https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen?

Comment: Since there are over 10,000 user log entry and a given year only has much less say 1000 entry, I figured front end JS would have to hide a lot of options and cause possible glitch. However, I haven't tried this, and it just might work. Thanks!

Comment: It will be less overhead if all of the `option` elements begin life in a hidden state, via CSS (`display: hidden;`). Then you selectively show the appropriate options at the appropriate times, hiding all others. See https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/